# Can I use raspberry pi on tv

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am looking forward to buy a rasberry pi but I am confused can it do the following things I want.

1. Can I use it as an Android for making my TV smart. ( I have HDMI in my TV. It's a led tv 3 years old )
2. Can I dual boot it so that I can play my PC games with controller attached to my raspberry pi? Like from parsec or any other software?  ( Looking forward to play GTA V , Portal , Inside , etc
3. I have my PC in my other room and I want to work on my PC while it streams the game on raspberry pi when I work? ( I have ryzen 5 with 8gb ram and 1050ti )
4. Any interesting projects I can do with raspberry pi for home use?

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi comes typically installed with a Linux distribution, and yes, you can use it, together with specific software, as a media server. But then, your TV is eventually not capable of connecting to your LAN, and maybe it does not understand the protocol. You have to check this out first.

For all other specified uses, the Raspberry Pi is rather inadeguate, because too slow, low on memory or simply hard- and software incompatible.